# Biometric dialog issue on the devices with fingerprint scanner on screen

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I use 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1' to show biometric prompt on the device before using it, that is explain why user can user fingerprint in application and button to deny

it
    [image]

```
mBiometricManager = new BiometricManager.BiometricBuilder(context)
                    .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.screen_login_biometric_prompt_title))
                    .setSubtitle(context.getString(R.string.screen_login_biometric_prompt_subtitle))
                    .setDescription(context.getString(R.string.screen_login_biometric_prompt_description))
                    .setNegativeButtonText(context.getString(R.string.screen_login_biometric_prompt_negative_text))
                    .build();
```

But on the devices with scanner that is **on the screen** this is not shown, just grey button to touch:

[image]
How to show this dialog, like in the other devices:

Comment: which device is not working? Make, model, etc.

Comment: hi, @IsaiDamier oneplus 7 pro, android 9

Comment: hello @IsaiDamier, do you know how the situation is now?